# What is 'gentlemen's kitchen'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

This first master of mine, as I may call him, was a smith, and my principal employment was working his bellows, which were the same kind as I had seen in my vicinity. They were in some respects not unlike the stoves here in **gentlemen's kitchens**; and were covered over with leather; and in the middle of that leather a stick was fixed, and a person stood up, and worked it, in the same manner as is done to pump water out of a cask with a hand pump.

---

It's from 'The Interesting Narrative of the Life of Olaudah Equiano' (1789)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing more than a kitchen belonging to a gentleman.

He is saying that the bellows that belonged to his first master were similar to the kinds of stoves that people of wealth and class can afford to have in their kitchens.